# OpenCV python vstack changes width

Tags: python-2.7, opencv, numpy

I'm using OpenCV 3.0.0 with Python 2.7 and trying something that ought to be simple.

I want to stack images vertically.

This simple example:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

comb = np.vstack((row_0, row_1))
cv2.imwrite('foo.png', comb)
```

consistently produces a `foo.png` that is drastically narrower (in the browser) than `row_0` and `row_1`.

Details:

```
row_0.shape
(1074, 785, 3)

row_1.shape
(1187, 785, 3)

comb.shape
(2261, 785, 3)
```

If I look at `row_0.png` in the browser, it is WAY wider than `foo.png`.

**Question**

How can I alter my code so `row_0.png` is the same width as `foo.png` in the browser?

Answer (score 1):

`np.vstack` does two things - make sure the inputs are at least 2d (here they are 3d), and joins them on axis=0 (rows).  In other words

```
np.concatenate((row0, row1), axis=0)
```

That's what I see happening - two dimensions are the same, the first is the sum of the 2 inputs:

```
(1074, 785, 3)
+
(1187, 785, 3)
=
(2261, 785, 3)
```

If the `comb` looks narrower, it is probably because of scaling. The ratio of 2nd dim to 1st has gotten smaller; that's to be expected if you join 2 arrays in this way.  And given the dimensions, that's the only possible way.

Viewed as arrays, `comb` has more rows, same number of columns.  But if 2261 is the image display width, then relative height will be less.